# Passing variable from AJAX success function to PHP Variable

Tags: php, ajax

How to use A1 variable in PHP Variable on index.php (for example $var):

**index.js**

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'url',
            type: 'post',
            data: {member_id : noVam},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response) {
                $("#A1").val(response.tedadQest);
)}
```

Comment: what I understand, you want: `data: {member_id : noVam, var: $('#A1').val()},`

Comment: I want to use A1 value, in if condition (in index.php)

Comment: so, in my snippet you would send the value in A1 as $_GET['var'] to php. `if($_GET['var'] == 'something') {` (and afterward you will place part of the resulting response back into #A1

Comment: I run the code below without problems :
`<input type="text" id="A1" name="A1">`
Output is a number(example:10), Now I want to run the following if statement : 
`<?php
$v = A1;
if ($v < "15") {
echo "Have a good day";
}
?>`

Comment: That is basic PHP, and already given by me above. Code could be (without copying to $v: `if($_GET['var'] < 15) { echo 'have a good day'; }`

Comment: and if you need the value more often and you do need a $v: `$v = $_GET['var']; `. But a check if it is numeric etc. could be in place

Comment: Your code is for the time when it has $ _POST value, Please see the index.js codes on this link : [link](http://codersfolder.com/2016/07/crud-with-php-mysqli-bootstrap-datatables-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: so not $_GET['var'] but $_POST['var']